# How do I resolve this multi project namespace issue?

Tags: c#

I have 3 projects

1. Company.Project
2. Company.Project.Business (inside is Interfaces folder, that contains ISomeService)
3. Company.Project.Web

In my SomeController I'm trying to do this:

```
private readonly Company.Project.Business.Interfaces.ISomeService _someService;
```

but i get this message

> The type or namespace name 'Business' does not exist in the namespace 'Company.Project' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I've imported the `Company.Project.Business` reference into my Web Project and added

```
using Company.Project.Business.Interfaces;
```

at the top of the `SomeControlller` class but I get the red squiggly under Business indicating that there is no `Business` class under `Company.Project` and that I should create it (which I don't need to do since I'm really just trying to use the project `Company.Project.Business`.

SOLVED:
As @Tim mentioned, the Company.Project.Business wouldn't compile because I had duplicated class names during a bad merge get into its .csproj. Thank you once again @Tim!

Comment: The folder isn't relevant, is `ISomeService` actually within a namespace scope for `Company.Project.Business.Interfaces`?

Comment: When you say imported, do you mean you added the project as a reference to the consuming project (i.e., added Company.Project.Business to the Company.Project.Web project)?

Comment: Is the Business class public?

Comment: what is the namespace of the class you are trying to use?

Comment: @Tim, by imported I mean I already have the proper reference to both of these projects in my web project.

Comment: @Spikolynn, Bussiness is not a class, its a project (Company.Project.Business)

Comment: @Charles Mager, ISomeService is defined in namespace Company.Project.Business.Interfaces

Comment: @User123 - Does the `Company.Project.Businesss` project compile?  Did you add it as a project reference or a direct reference to the DLL?  I've seen this happen when the referenced assembly doesn't build for some reason (and it can be a bit of a bear to track it down if you have a number of dependent assemblies)

Comment: If you've done all those things you say you have, my only other thought is to ensure that the target frameworks of both projects are compatible.  You'll see this issue if a project targeting e.g. .NET 4.0 references a project targeting .NET 4.5.

Comment: What is in Company.Project project. Remove this project if it is not used.

Comment: @Tim, ding ding ding! Project didnt compile because I had duplicated class names in the Company.Project.Business.csproj. Probably due to a bad merge. Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome.  @CharlesMager suggestion is also a good thing to check if you run into this in the future.   This happens to me a lot (different framework targets).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Tim mentioned in the comments above, the Company.Project.Business wouldn't compile because I had duplicated class names during a bad merge get into its .csproj. Selecting his comment as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You add the reference to a project but inside the code you need to reference the namespace.

In your interface declaration how did you specify your namespace? It should be like this:

```
namespace Company.Project.Business.Interfaces
```

If you declare it only as Company.Project it won't work.

Comment: It is specified as you said. But the issue was as @Tim mentioned in teh comments above, the Company.Project.Business wouldn't compile becauase of a bad merge resulting in duplicated names of one of the classes. Thanks anyway!